# Errno 121, duplicate key on write or update?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`restaurants`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`restaurants` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
  `min_order` INT NOT NULL ,
  `food_types` SET('pizza', 'sushi', 'osetian_pie') NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`regions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`regions` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `restaurant` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `restaurant_idx` (`restaurant` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `restaurant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`restaurants` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`food`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`food` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `type` ENUM('pizza', 'sushi', 'osetian_pie') NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `ingredients` VARCHAR(256) NULL ,
  `image` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`food_variant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`food_variant` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `size` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  `weight` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  `price` INT NOT NULL ,
  `food` INT NOT NULL ,
  `restaurant` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `food_idx` (`food` ASC) ,
  INDEX `restaurant_idx` (`restaurant` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `food`
    FOREIGN KEY (`food` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`food` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `restaurant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`restaurants` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

Error is:
    Executing SQL script in server
    ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mydb.food_variant' (errno: 121)
```

I see no duplicate constraints. Where is it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is likely because you have named at least one constraint with the same identifier as a column:

```
/* You already have a column named `restaurant` in this table, 
   but are naming the FK CONSTRAINT `restaurant` also... */
CONSTRAINT `restaurant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`restaurants` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Should use a different identifier for the constraint like `fk_restaurant` as in :

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`restaurants` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

And same thing in the `food` table:

```
  /* Name it fk_food */
  CONSTRAINT `fk_food`
    FOREIGN KEY (`food` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`food` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  /* Name it fk_restaurant */
  CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurant`
    FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`restaurants` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Those are the only three I see, but there could be others I missed.

Comment: In case someone hits this problem. I was getting the errno 121 even after changing the constraint names across multiple tables. The problem was that even across different tables you cannot have the same constraint name. I was using 'fk_entryid' in table1 and table2 and had to change them to 'fk_table1_entryid' and 'fk_table2_entryid' respectively to make it work. This happened with MySQLWorkbench and MariaDB in case that matters.

Answer (score 19):

This answer comes from [the comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994919/can-not-create-table-in-workbench-errno-121#comment59420118_12994930) from @Michael Berkowski. I post it as an answer as it actually worked for me:

> I was getting the errno 121 even after changing the constraint names
>   across multiple tables. The problem was that even across different
>   tables you cannot have the same constraint name. I was using
>   `fk_entryid` in `table1` and `table2` and had to change them to
>   `fk_table1_entryid` and `fk_table2_entryid` respectively to make it
>   work.

Answer (score 8):

All the answers above are superb but didn't solve my problem even after i dropped all my tables, but everything worked perfectly and the migration ran smoothly after i dropped my DB and created it again.... It seems the keys are cached and aren't cleared after tables are dropped.

**Note** : This is not an answer to the question but my experience that i felt might help another person.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. I had to drop the database completely. My guess is something got messed up some time ago when I had issues stopping mysql daemon and had to kill it forcefully.

Comment: same with me. just dropped the database and re-import it solved the issue

Comment: We had the same issue. We were able to solve it by stopping and restarting the MySQL/MariaDB server. Hence, dropping the database might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a response to @peter-moses, as I had exactly the same issues as he did.

I solved that problem by adding `--add-drop-database` to my dump command. Its documented here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/

My final command looks like this:

`mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --single-transaction --all-databases --add-drop-database`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was very strange caching issue. I was not able to create a new foreign key constraint, although the name of the key was unique. Restarting MariaDB server was not the solution, but checking both `Foreign Keys` and `References` lists.

For example, in my Database navigator (I am using DBeaver) all my `Foreign Keys` lists were empty. However, when I navigated to the referenced table and checked its `References` list, I was able to see the entries. By the way, these entries were also not visible when executing a query against `information_schema`. ‍♂️

After removing the references from this list I was able to create new foreign keys.

**Edit**

Executing `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` and checking its `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section might also help, as it gives additional information/context for the problem.

Comment: I'm using DBeaver 22.3.1, and "Foreign Keys" node doesn't show any existing fkeys, which is a system bug, I believe. In fact, foreign key was there and was able to verify it using on DOS (not in DBeaver script)--  select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'mydb' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DBeaver22.3.1 and suffered the same issue as below:
That is, [Foreign keys] node didn't show any item on it(see below fig.)

[image]

However, using following select statement, it's existance was obvious(see 2nd image). Therefore, error says "duplicate" if I try to create a foreign key with the same name.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'webstore' 
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

[image]