# Duplicate key on write or update?

Tags: mysql, sql

### Duplicate key on write or update

First i will like to acknowledge the fact that, i have been to **similar posts**, but i couldn't find a way to solve this annoying issue which i face as of present.I am using **mysql workbench** and i keep getting this error.

1. **On workbench :** ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'database.path' (errno: 121)
2. **Use "Perror 121" on command line :** MySQL error code 121: Duplicate key on write or update

At the end of the log, it shows **9 successful operations** and **1 failure** with only **path** table visible in the logs.

Any help and suggestion is welcomed.I think the mysql compiler doesn't really do a good Job when it comes to signifying the actual issue for debugging.

Comment: Did you go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994919/can-not-create-table-in-workbench-errno-121 ?

Comment: Maybe not in realtion to your problem, but, as_detail link seems wrong? as_detail.As_Name=as_path.A_No. Shouldnt it link to the PK in as_details?

Comment: @KayNelson actually workbench doesn't literally specify the exact relation with the lines. It just points to the tables using the middle as you can see with most. as_detail_AS_No = as_path_AS_No

Comment: Hmm good morning...and that makes more sense as i now see all relations are wrong hehe :) But seems to me a UNIQUE/PK fields gets a double value or a FK contraints name might be the problem? Can you post the create statement?

Comment: @KayNelson good morning,thanks very much for your efforts in trying to help. I found the issue to be strongly related to the link posted by rakeshjain.I answered my problem.

Comment: Constraint Name is unique. Not per table. Thus if same constraint name is used elsewhere it makes thing bit difficult for mysql to handle.

Answer (score 141):

Sorry guys, I found the problem. It is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994919/can-not-create-table-in-workbench-errno-121).

Which was hinted by **rakeshjain.**

It may be deleted as a duplicate post by admin.

The answer is, I had two CONSTRAINTS on different tables with the same name:

CONSTRAINT **`Update_ID_fk`**  -->  Changed one and problem solved.

Comment: This happened to me when I tried adding a column to a  `UNIQUE` index by dropping and adding the key in the same query. I got an error message also containing a random table name and wrong data. Very strange. Dropping the index in one query and adding in a second worked fine.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea! Thanks for your solution posted Here - I found it much clearer than the post being linked to.

Comment: Changed the constraint name and works!

Comment: This happened to me because someone made a backup table :|

Comment: Thank you for answer. At first did not understand, believed, that in multiple tables can use the same `CONSTRAINT` names (similarly as column names), but no, in each table must unique `CONSTRAINT` names

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It would have taken me hours to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 68):

Your Foreign key names must be unique

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11042455)

Comment: @Vasfed seems like it does

Comment: It most certainly does provide an answer.

Comment: it provide a solution based on the (implicit) answer, since the question seek (implicitly) a solution

Comment: I would like to extend the answer by "Your Foreign key names must be unique... across entire schema/database. This means different tables cannot have the same name for a FK"