# Error 1064 when forward engineering a ER diagram in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, erd

I'm trying to forward engineer an ER diagram in Workbench to create my schema and I'm getting an error. I'm using mySql Workbench for mac.

This is the Error message I'm getting:

```
 Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  INDEX `city_id_fk_idx` (`city_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `county_id_idx` (`cou' at line 13
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `k00243666_property_bubble`.`addresses`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `k00243666_property_bubble`.`addresses` (
          `address_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `address1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `address2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `eircode` VARCHAR(7) NULL,
          `town_id` INT NULL,
          `city_id` INT NULL,
          `county_id` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
          INDEX `town_id_fk_idx` (`town_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `city_id_fk_idx` (`city_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `county_id_idx` (`county_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `town_id_fk`
            FOREIGN KEY (`town_id`)
            REFERENCES `k00243666_property_bubble`.`town` (`town_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `city_id_fk`
            FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`)
            REFERENCES `k00243666_property_bubble`.`city` (`city_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `county_id`
            FOREIGN KEY (`county_id`)
            REFERENCES `k00243666_property_bubble`.`county` (`county_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Does anyone know why i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your version of MariaDB does not support `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE` as applied to an index definition.  In any case, indices should be visible by default, so you should not even need to specify `VISIBLE`.  Try using this syntax:

```
INDEX town_id_fk_idx (town_id),
INDEX city_id_fk_idx (city_id),
INDEX county_id_idx (county_id)
```

[Here is a link](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7317) to a feature request which was made to MariaDB.  There does not appear to an `INVISIBLE` syntax for turning off indices to the optimizer.  However, it presents an alternative:

```
ALTER TABLE addresses DISABLE KEYS;
```

This would make all indices invisible to the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solved part of the problem, now I'm getting a different error:Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `k00243666_property_bubble`.`user_status` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Comment: @LaurDragulin Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The site doesn't work this way.  If you have a substantially different problem now from what you asked, then you need to open a new question.  SO is not a blog site, where you keep asking follow-ups.

Comment: I sort it out, I also had the constraints duplicates, fixed it now, thanks very much Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Also thanks to this guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/20512955/10739429, that was the fix for my second error.